# Infracciones de las políticas Admob

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, admob

Hoy he recibido un aviso de infracción por parte de Admob diciendo:

Código de anuncio modificado: cambiar el tamaño de los marcos de anuncios

Esto es una infracción de las políticas. Debe solucionarla.
ANUNCIOS MODIFICADOS: los editores no pueden alterar en modo alguno el funcionamiento de los anuncios Google, por ejemplo, no se permite modificar el tamaño de los marcos de los anuncios de forma que estos aparezcan recortados o que oculten el nombre Anuncios Google.

Alguien sabe como resolver este problema? no especifica nada de información.

Donde se visualiza el anuncio en la parte de .xml seria:

```
<LinearLayout  android:gravity="bottom" 
       android:orientation="vertical"  
       android:scrollbars="none" 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/ad_main"/> 
</LinearLayout>
```

codigo que utilizo admob:

```
import com.google.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobAdapter;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

public static String AD_UNIT_ID_BANNER =""

AdView adView = new AdView(context);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId(ConfiguracioGeneral.AD_UNIT_ID_BANNER);
layout.addView(adView);
adView.loadAd(adrequest);
return adView;
```

Siempre ha funcionado y nunca de he tenido ningún error.

utilizo la versión:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.3.0' -> puedo actualizar a la version 19.2.0
```

Alguien sabe si es por tema de actualización? no especifica nada...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He visto que se recibe este email:

> **Modified ad code: Resizing Ad Frames**: Publishers are not permitted to
> alter the behavior of AdMob ads in any way. This includes resizing ad
> frames to cut off parts of ads or hiding the Ads by Google moniker.

al parecer es cuando actualizamos el targetSDK con el cual generamos la aplicaciòn y es debido a que aunque aparentemente no realizamos ningùn cambio pero tenemos definidos espacios como "paddings", ejemplo:

> ```
> <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
>     xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:id="@+id/adView"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
> ```

> ```
>     android:paddingTop="3dp"
> ```

> ```
>     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
>     ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
>     ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
> </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
> ```

Puedes revisar esta informaciòn (inglès)

https://medium.com/@debuggingisfun/modified-ad-code-resizing-ad-frames-6c6ddc6dfbba

En el caso de tu contenedor cambia de "fill_parent" a "match_parent" :

```
<LinearLayout  android:gravity="bottom" 
       android:orientation="vertical"  
       android:scrollbars="none" 
       android:layout_width="match_parent" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/ad_main"/> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto, establece el tamaño del bannner en el XML

```
ads:adSize="BANNER"
```

Y elimina la sentencia.

```
adView.setAdSize(AdZise.SMART_BANNER);
```

Comment: Que cambio realizarìa esto, ya lo probaste?, es lo mismo solo que se definirìa el tamaño por còdigo.

Comment: No lo he podido probar porque no tengo el mismo problema, sólo que siempre he utilizado esa configuración y nunca he tenido problemas con AdMob. Pruébalo y dinos si te sirvió. También puedes escribirle a Google Support y pedirles que te describan bien el problema que han encontrado, así te centras en una sola cosa y es más fácil de solucionar.

Answer (score 0):

Cierto en mi caso creo que es el tema del "match_parent"

He actualizado la versión de google play  + modificado el XML

El codigo final seria este:

```
<LinearLayout  android:gravity="bottom" 
       android:orientation="vertical"  
       android:layout_width="match_parent" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/ad_main"/> 
</LinearLayout>
```

**Tambien he eliminado:**
android:scrollbars="none" y android:layout_width="fill_parent"

He actualizado la aplicación y he pedido una revisión por parte de Admob a ver si tengo suerte.

Ya estoy actualizando la otras apps antes que admob detecte el mismo error.

Muchas gracias por las respuestas ;-)